# Gmail API OAuth error: Parameter not allowed for this message type: redirect_uri

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api

Gmail OAuth API has been working well until Feb 17th, and `POST /o/oauth2/token` randomly returns this error while refreshing OAuth token:

> Parameter not allowed for this message type: redirect_uri

The error occurs about 1 out of 10 times. What's strange is that, after receiving this error, the next exact same request succeeded. So this is not related to "redirect_uri" as suggested by the error message.

"Parameter not allowed for this message type" has been reported in other StackOverflow posts, but they are all persistent errors and can be resolved by fixing the parameters. While the error we got is temporary. The 10% rate is costly to the user experience.

Has anyone seen similar behavior lately?

Comment: Have you tried the solution in this google group post? Have you check if you are sending to o/oauth2/token instead of o/oauth2/auth?

Comment: We experienced the exact same issue since few hours. We updated our code to remove the "redirect_uri" automatically added by our third party library to quick fix the problem. Keep in touch.

Comment: Removing the "redirect_uri" parameter does it. I've contact Gmail API support and they confirmed Google is updating the old API behavior in batches, that's why it failed intermittently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems Google has recently changed the url for getting a new access token from a refresh token. The older url was https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token and the new one is https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token.

Also I remember that `redirect_uri` was previously among the parameters for getting a new access token, but it no longer seems to be there: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline. Just look at the HTTP/REST example.

It is possible that just removing `redirect_uri` works even with the older url, but I think it is wise to both change the url and remove `redirect_uri`.

Comment: Thanks, Google API team confirmed that redirect_uri should be removed from the refresh token request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to add a comment above, but we've been seeing a similar issue too with intermittent failures on oauth.

Removing the "redirect_uri" worked, though that makes me nervous since the documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer says to include it.

What does work, though, and allows us to keep the "redirect_uri" is updating our url from https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token